# How would I write an ActionFilter that ensures AntiForgeryTokens are used for every Post operation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter, antiforgerytoken, http-verbs

I want to use `AntiForgeryTokens` on every HttpPost Action using an ActionFilter that is in a controller named `ControllerBase` that every other controller inherits from.

I want to do this by creating an ActionFilter that inherits from `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` which takes an argument that tells it what HTTP verbs to apply itself to. I then want to apply that filter on  `ControllerBase` to ensure that the `AntiForgeryToken` is checked for EVERY POST operation on the entire site.

I was looking into using [this solution](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2010/04/14/guarding-against-csrf-attacks-in-asp-net-mvc2.aspx), but

- `AuthorizationContext Constructor (ControllerContext)` is an obsolete constructor involved and I am not sure how to rebuild the code using the recommended `AuthorizationContext(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)`.
- <strike>It does not appear to use the AntiForgeryToken by default as I get the following error: `A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid` after every post action.</strike>

**How should I rewrite my ActionFilter to meet current non-obsolete standards and to properly use an anti-forgery token on every `[HttpPost]` verb?**

<strike>Do I have to include an anti-forgery token in every form myself (I am thinking I do)? (as opposed to it being automatically generated - don't laugh, I'm curious)</strike> **Update:** As pointed out in the comments; Yes, this has to be done with every form.

Here is the code from my ControllerBase for reference:

```
[UseAntiForgeryTokenOnPostByDefault]
public class ControllerBase : Controller 
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class BypassAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class UseAntiForgeryTokenOnPostByDefault : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (ShouldValidateAntiForgeryTokenManually(filterContext))
            {
                var authorizationContext = new AuthorizationContext(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext);

                //Use the authorization of the anti forgery token, 
                //which can't be inhereted from because it is sealed
                new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute().OnAuthorization(authorizationContext);
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// We should validate the anti forgery token manually if the following criteria are met:
        /// 1. The http method must be POST
        /// 2. There is not an existing [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute on the action
        /// 3. There is no [BypassAntiForgeryToken] attribute on the action
        /// </summary>
        private static bool ShouldValidateAntiForgeryTokenManually(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var httpMethod = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;

            //1. The http method must be POST
            if (httpMethod != "POST") return false;

            // 2. There is not an existing anti forgery token attribute on the action
            var antiForgeryAttributes =
                filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute), false);

            if (antiForgeryAttributes.Length > 0) return false;

            // 3. There is no [BypassAntiForgeryToken] attribute on the action
            var ignoreAntiForgeryAttributes =
                filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (BypassAntiForgeryTokenAttribute), false);

            if (ignoreAntiForgeryAttributes.Length > 0) return false;

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add a filter to the Global Filters collection. I'm not sure it would be necessary to put it on a base controller.

Comment: I understand that, but would prefer to put it within the `ControllerBase` for my current architecture.

Comment: Do I have to include an anti-forgery token in every form myself?... You might be able to write a custom BeginForm HtmlHelper that will emit this automatically. Otherwise, yes, you would need to output the token on each form manually.

Comment: @danludwig Thank you, that seems like what I should and will do.

Comment: @Ecnalyr        `public static MvcForm BeginSecureForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
        {             var mvcForm = htmlHelper.BeginForm(routeValues);
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(htmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken().ToHtmlString());            
            return mvcForm;
        }`

Comment: @felickz this post is over a year old.  Thanks anyway?  :)

Comment: @Ecnalyr .. not like they delete posts, trying to help the next guy

Comment: @felickz That's a very good point.  Keep it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate any `AuthorizationContext` or call the `OnAuthorization` method, simply:

```
if (ShouldValidateAntiForgeryTokenManually(filterContext))
{
    AntiForgery.Validate(filterContext.HttpContext, null);
}
```

Comment: Times are a changin: [Obsolete("This method is deprecated. Use the Validate() method instead.", error: true)] ... this is now wrapped with  `_worker.Validate(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));`

Answer (score 7):

I've used the following approach:

```
public class SkipCSRFCheckAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class AntiForgeryTokenFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (IsHttpPostRequest(filterContext) && !SkipCsrfCheck(filterContext))
            AntiForgery.Validate();
    }

    private static bool IsHttpPostRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        return filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.Post.ToString();
    }

    private static bool SkipCsrfCheck(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        return filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (SkipCSRFCheck), false).Any();
    }
}
```

Which enables us to disable it on a case-by-case basis using the SkipCSRFCheck attribute, and then registering it as a global filter in the Application_Start:

GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new AntiForgeryTokenFilter());